# Populating a Menu from a Database

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I found some very useful code on populating a menu from a database and customised it a bit but I am struggling to create a third level to menu as in the below example(2.1.1 and 2.1.2)

1. Home
2. About Us
   2.1 Management Team
   2.1.1 Team Member 1
   2.1.2 Team Member 2 
   2.2 Company Information
3. Contact Us

I have listed my code below.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Imports iconCloud_BL
Partial Class Main
    Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    Public Params As New List(Of SqlParameter)
    Dim clsDatabase As New clsDatabaseLogic
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If Not Me.IsPostBack Then

            Dim dt As DataTable = Me.GetData(0, 2)
            PopulateMenu(dt, 0, Nothing)


        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function GetData(parentMenuId As Integer, role As Integer) As DataTable
        Dim query As String = "SELECT [menusMenuId], [menusTitle], [menusDescription], [menusUrl] FROM [configMenus] WHERE menusParentMenuId = @ParentMenuId AND menusRole = @Role"
        Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("iconDataConnections").ConnectionString
        Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
            Dim dt As New DataTable()
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(query)
                Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParentMenuId", parentMenuId)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Role", role)
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                    sda.Fill(dt)
                End Using
            End Using
            Return dt
        End Using
    End Function


    Private Sub PopulateMenu(dt As DataTable, parentMenuId As Integer, parentMenuItem As MenuItem)
        Dim dtChild As DataTable
        Dim currentPage As String = Path.GetFileName(Request.Url.AbsolutePath)
        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            Dim rowcount = getMaxRows()

            Dim menuItem As New MenuItem() With {
             .Value = row("menusMenuId").ToString(),
             .Text = row("menusTitle").ToString(),
              .NavigateUrl = row("menusUrl").ToString(),
             .Selected = row("menusUrl").ToString().EndsWith(currentPage, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
            }

                If parentMenuId = 0 Then
                    mainMenu.Items.Add(menuItem)
                    dtChild = Me.GetData(Integer.Parse(menuItem.Value), 2)
                    PopulateMenu(dtChild, Integer.Parse(menuItem.Value), menuItem)
                ElseIf parentMenuId > 0 Then

                For i As Integer = 0 To rowcount
                    mainMenu.Items.Add(menuItem)
                    dtChild = Me.GetData(Integer.Parse(i), 2)
                    PopulateMenu(dtChild, Integer.Parse(i), menuItem)

                Next
            Else
                        parentMenuItem.ChildItems.Add(menuItem)
                End If
            Next

    End Sub

    Public Function getMaxRows()

        clsDatabase.SQLCmd.CommandText = "sp_iconCloud_configMenuRowsCount"
        clsDatabase.SQLCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure


        clsDatabase.SQLCmd.Connection = clsDatabase.SQLConn
        clsDatabase.SQLConn.Open()
        Dim count As Integer = clsDatabase.SQLCmd.ExecuteScalar()
        clsDatabase.SQLConn.Close()
        clsDatabase.SQLCmd.Parameters.Clear()


        Return count

    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: What is the issue with the code? Unable to create 2.1.1 Team Member?

Comment: yes, I tried by adding the code below into a loop but still not working        
                    mainMenu.Items.Add(menuItem)
                    dtChild = Me.GetData(Integer.Parse(i), 2)
                    PopulateMenu(dtChild, Integer.Parse(i), menuItem)